# how to Add if-match counter in header in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I am doing some performance testing for my API and it uses if-match header which should be incremented for the subsequent request.
I add a counter for that thread group but the values are not in the order they are unique and incremented but they are not in ascending order.

they are in the form: 210,150,213 etc. and it should be 150,152,152,153...

Is their a way in Jmeter with which I can achieve it.

```
here is the log:
018-10-30 19:53:18,629 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>232
2018-10-30 19:53:18,629 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>245
2018-10-30 19:53:18,629 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>231
2018-10-30 19:53:18,629 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>229
2018-10-30 19:53:18,644 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>246
2018-10-30 19:53:18,660 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>249
2018-10-30 19:53:18,750 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>251
2018-10-30 19:53:18,782 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>252
2018-10-30 19:53:18,782 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>248
2018-10-30 19:53:18,782 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>247
2018-10-30 19:53:18,875 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Counter value::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>253
```

Answer (score 0):

We are not telepathic enough to tell what's wrong without seeing your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and "counter" (whatever it is) config.

If you're looking for a way to generate an incrementing number no matter of which thread is being executed at the moment - the easiest option is going for [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) in GLOBAL mode like:

```
${__counter(FALSE,)}
```

It will return an incremented number each time it will be called, no matter which thread invoked it. Hopefully this is something you're looking for:

[image]

Just in case check out [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article.